# How to use jboss with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

I've built my project successfully. My war is located in target dir and I try to run the war on the jboss here is the part of pom.xml that says jboss where to look for war..

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jbossHome>C:\jboss-4.2.2.GA</jbossHome>
                    <serverName>all</serverName>
                    <fileName>target/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war</fileName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Now I start it with maven here is the message :

```
[INFO] [jboss:start]
[INFO] Starting JBoss...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

But the localost isn't working, what did I forget to do ?

Comment: Check out server log messages.

Comment: @Vinegar I mean it works when I manually copy the war file to my jboss then start it from eclipse or from bin, I just wanna start it as a maven plugin, when I run jetty .. it runs with no problems

Comment: so are you running jboss or jetty?

Comment: I'm trying to run jboss, but I managed to run jetty without any configuration by just saying start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see the `hard-deploy` and `start` goals in your pom (the latter is apparently there somewhere if you get this output, just missing from your post). Also, I use my own server configuration instead of `all` - but that should not make a big difference in theory. And the `fileName` property is not used by the plugin, you don't need it. JBoss automatically finds your war file if it is deployed properly (that's why you need the `hard-deploy` goal).

My configuration looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.sp1</version>
        <configuration>
            <jbossHome>...</jbossHome>
            <serverName>MyServer</serverName>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>redeploy-and-restart-server</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>hard-deploy</goal>
                    <goal>start</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Note that the JBoss maven plugin does only work properly if you bind your server to localhost and to the JNDI port 1099. I guess if you are using the `all` server configuration, you haven't tampered with those settings, but it's good to know nevertheless.

If your server is still not running, you should check the log files in the `all/log` directory to see what's going on.

Comment: I'm looking at logs I don't know what I'm supposed to look for

Comment: @Péter Török you're the main man :D I started it with your configuration :D

Comment: I saw you answered quite a lot questions about maven, how did you get so good, which books you read ?

Comment: @c0mrade glad to hear that, although I don't consider myself "good" yet - I am still learning, mostly the hard way, by improving the maven configuration of our legacy project. For reading I can recommend Maven: the Definitive Guide. It is even available on the net for free, google it.